# Correlation Matrix Problem of Three Decomposition Level of DWT

Tags: matlab, wavelet, matrix, discrete-wavelet-transform

I'm trying to apply a DWT with 3 composition levels and the following question arose when calculating the composition matrix.
The step I'm trying to follow is:

The DWT coefficientes are obtained from filtering operations and are divided in approximation ($cA$) and detail coefficients ($cD$).

[Three Decomposition Level of DWT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAkxm.png)

If a signal $f(n)$ is scaled up to a defined decomposition level, then, it will be producing a wavelet matrix $M(J+1,n)$, this matrix is analysed using its correlation matrix defined by:

$$
\boldsymbol{Y}=\frac{\boldsymbol{M} \times \boldsymbol{M}^T}{n}
$$

where $n$ is the total sample numbers. Therefore, it has a matrix $Y(J+1,J+1)$ which contains the scaled frequency information of the signal.

Each level of decomposition will have a matrix with a different size, so how am I going to analyze the correlation matrix? Should it be done individually? Should I complete with zeros? Should I only analyze $cD_3$ AND $cA_3$?

For example, for a discrete signal that I am applying dwt MATLAB toolbox. It will first generate a $cD_1$  (9x1), $cD_2$  (6x1), $cD_3$ (4x1) and $cA_3$ (4x1).

Each coefficient has a different size.

Reference [Algorithm for transformer differential protection based on wavelet correlation modes](https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1049/iet-gtd.2015.1147)

**MATLAB CODE**:

```
for i = 1:num_windows
current_start_index = start_index + (i - 1) * step_size;
current_end_index = current_start_index + half_cycle_samples - 1;

windowed_Ida(:, i) = Ida_n(current_start_index:current_end_index);
windowed_Idb(:, i) = Idb_n(current_start_index:current_end_index);
windowed_Idc(:, i) = Idc_n(current_start_index:current_end_index);
    
  swc_a = swt(windowed_Ida(:, i),3,"db4");
  n_a = length(swc_a);
  
  Y1 = (swc_a * swc_a') / n_a;
  
  swc_b = swt(windowed_Idb(:, i),3,"db4");
  n_b = length(swc_b);
  
  Y2 = (swc_b * swc_b') / n_a;
 
  swc_c = swt(windowed_Idc(:, i),3,"db4");
  n_c = length(swc_c);
  
  Y3 = (swc_b * swc_b') / n_a;
  
  YT = (Y1 + Y2 + Y3)/3;

  D = eig(YT);
  MCW(start_index + (i - 1) * step_size : start_index + (i - 1) * step_size + half_cycle_samples - 1) = max(D);
```

end

Comment: Can you share the reference on this correlation matrix?

Comment: Of course, [link](https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1049/iet-gtd.2015.1147)

Comment: Is $J$ the decomposition level? What type of analysis are you trying to do with the correlation matrix?

Comment: J is the decomposition level

Comment: The signal I am analyzing is formed by a vector (7680x1). With 32 samples per cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [paper](https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1049/iet-gtd.2015.1147) you linked to is problematic, with lots of typos (e.g, *the size of this "wavelet"* instead of *the size of this "matrix"*), and no information on how they actually build this "wavelet matrix".

The most straight-forward way to go about it is to use a [Stationary Wavelet Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_wavelet_transform), which gets rid of the downsampling operation at each stage, giving you coefficients $cA_i$ and $cD_i$ of the same length, allowing you to build that matrix easily (assuming you know which order these should be stacked).

Comment: I applied the MATLAB [swt](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/swt.html) function, it generated a matrix M(J,n) and not M(J+1,n). Will I have problems with this?

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/swt.html#mw_4560a5b8-850d-490e-9d8a-64388086d6dc), if you call `swc=swt(x,J,wname)`, you should get a matrix `swc` of size `(J+1,n)`.

Comment: I'm still trying to apply the paper's algorithm. But without success. 
I put the algorithm in the post.